# PHP rename does not work

Tags: php, curl, rename

I download a file with cURL using option CURLOPT_FILE and then try to rename the downloaded file, for example, from "1.txt" to "2.txt". It fails to rename the file.

PHP throws an error:

> "Warning: rename(E:\.../test/1.txt,E:\.../test/2.txt) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in E:\.../test\lib\CURL\Download.php  on line 51"

After that I run just one-line-script:

```
<?php rename("E:\.../test/1.txt","E:\.../test/2.txt");
```

and renaming succeeds.

Why does it work now? The same renaming operation.

Some other thing:

1. Windows OS
2. File "1.txt" indeed exists
3. I use absolute path when renaming
4. before renaming i close file handle used by cURL with fclose()

What is wrong? How can I rename the downloaded file in the first script without an error?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think PHP supports the 3 dots syntax (...), that is a windows command line specific thing.

Also: you might want to try using realpath on the initial name to make sure it exists

**Edit:**

as a solution, just do

```
<?php rename("E:\..\../test/1.txt","E:\..\../test/2.txt");
```

Should solve your problem :)

Comment: sorry, i wrote it bad 3 dots actually mean: E:\xampp\htdocs\test\1.txt

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful with Windows-style directory separators (`\`) in strings. You're using double-quoted strings, so any single backslash will be interpreted as an escape sequence, not a path separator. Either use forward slashes, or single quotes:

```
$src = "E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\1.txt";
$src = 'E:\xampp\htdocs\test\1.txt';
$src = "E:/xampp/htdocs/test/1.txt";
```

all come out to the same thing, but if you try:

```
$src = "E:\xampp\htdocs\test\1.txt";
```

PHP will evaluate to that to:

```
$src = "E:xampphtdocstest1.txt";
```

Comment: Also, forward slashes work fine on Windows (apparently php fixes them for you), so maybe best to just always use / and not worry about it, certainly helps with portability also.

Comment: I actualy use $src = dirname(__FILE__) . '/1.txt' - it does not work.
If i do $src = dirname(__FILE__) . '\1.txt' - also does not work. If I do just $src = '1.txt' also does not work. The renaming itself works as I said earlier but not directly after the file was downloaded but when I run PHP one more time.

Comment: Try adding some debugging before/after the rename call. See if $src exists before trying the rename, and if you're running this from the cli, pause the script (long sleep, keyboard input, etc...) and take a look in that directory to see what is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP says that running a second script afterwards, with the same rename line, works I don't see how either other current answer is relevant. My guess is you are using fopen to create a file resource, running curl_exec($ch); then attempting to rename the file without calling `fclose();` since the file will be closed automatically when leaving the script this would explain why a second script with the same code would work.

Comment: I am using fclose() in the end before renaming, i wrote it in the 4-th point :(

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem and i solve it by this code:

```
$oldname ='E:\.../test/1.txt';
$newname ='E:\.../test/2.txt';
rename($oldname,$newname);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.